# Take my word for it or

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, sentence-choice, sentence-usage

Suppose someone close is talking to you about his / her family problem which they have been dealing with during the e.g. past couple of weeks. You know where the problem is and try to explain it to him / her. They try to stand against your opinion because they doubt it is correct; but you are sure and say something to indicate this message that don't be worried and just believe me; I need to know which one of the following sentences is more idiomatic and natural in such sense:

> - You just accept my word.
> - You just take my word.
> - You just accept my word fro it.
> - You just take my word for it.

Comment: Which one do you think and why?

Answer (score 1):

The idiom is "to *take* someone's word for it", which means "to believe what someone says without investigating further. Here's the [source](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/word).